# Displaying pdf files without using external libraries

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, pdf

In my Angular app, I have included the following snippet in an html template:

```
<embed src="../assets/AOK_T2DM.pdf" style="width: 100%;height: 500px" type="application/pdf">
```

It appears as follows:

[image]

When I click open, the pdf file is downloaded.

How can I simply display the content instead of downloading it?

Answer (score 1):

```html
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf&embedded=true" frameborder="0" height="600" width="100%"></iframe>
```

Use Below Code

```
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=File_URL&embedded=true" frameborder="0" height="1100px" width="100%"></iframe>
```

Set height as per your need or give the height as 100% and set the height for the parent div.
Check and update if it works.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: Thank you, but this does the same thing; it only downloads it but not display the pdf file content... `<iframe src="../assets/AOK_T2DM.pdf" frameborder="0" height="1100px" width="100%"></iframe>`

Comment: Run the file in local host or live editor preview it may works.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: You can check this article to get an idea https://medium.com/@arya.bawanta/method-to-view-pdf-documents-on-your-websites-9d06dea9b21e